# Can a jade plant agitate allergies?

Tags: jade

I'm sensitive to pollen, dust, and pet dander, but my wife wants a [jade plant](http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crassula_ovata) for our apartment.  As far as I know, jade plants are a non-fragrant plant, and shouldn't produce any allergens, but I've never owned one before.

Can a jade plant cause any issues for those sensitive to allergens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If, when you say jade plant, you mean Crassula ovata, it should be fine - will need dusting to keep your allergy problems down though. It does flower, which means pollen, but rarely indoors and only after several years and only then if its in a very sunny spot.

You might find the following article useful:

http://www.beyondallergy.com/indoor-allergies/allergies-to-house-plants.php

Comment: Indeed I do mean the Crassula ovata.  I'll edit that into my question.  Thank you - this is  a very useful answer.